# 1C Битрикс: кастомный тип свойства инфоблока

Tags: битрикс, время

В Битриксе есть тип св-ва "Дата/Время", но нет типа "Время".

По гуглению о добавлении кастомного типа выдается только куча кода, без объяснений что делается и куда его вставлять.

В магазине решения для добавления этого типа я не нашел.

Прошу помочь примером/ссылкой

Comment: А чем плох вариант использовать это поле с фиксированной датой, отрезая ее в шаблоне?
Вы что там хотите хранить? Точное время или временные рамки?

Answer (score 8):

Опишу как быстро сделать кастомный тип свойства в Битриксе.
Для этого достаточно даже стартовых знаний по этой системе.

Вводная

Необходимо в файле init.php создать класс и обработчик который будет его вызывать.
Небольшой комментарий по файлу init.php. Часто его можно найти или в папке **/bitrix/php_interface/** или **/bitrix/php_interface/#id_сайта#** или **/local/php_interface/**. Если вы его там не нашли, то надо его создать. Важно отметить, что ошибки в файле критичны и если они будут допущены в коде, то сайт сразу ляжет.

Теперь сам код.

Я покажу очень простую и понятную заготовку:

```
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnIBlockPropertyBuildList", array("CIBlockNewProperty", "GetUserTypeDescription"));

class CIBlockNewProperty
{
    public function GetUserTypeDescription()
    {
        return array(
            "PROPERTY_TYPE"        => "S", #-----один из стандартных типов
            "USER_TYPE"            => "MYIDCODE", #-----идентификатор типа свойства
            "DESCRIPTION"          => "Название свойства",
            "GetPropertyFieldHtml" => array("CIBlockNewProperty", "GetPropertyFieldHtml"),
        );
    }

    /*--------- вывод поля свойства на странице редактирования ---------*/
    public function GetPropertyFieldHtml($arProperty, $value, $strHTMLControlName)
    {
        return '<input type="text" name="'.$strHTMLControlName["VALUE"].'" value="'.$value['VALUE'].'"> <input type="text" name="'.$strHTMLControlName["DESCRIPTION"].'" value="'.$value['DESCRIPTION'].'">';
    }
}
```

После этого в вашем списке свойств появится новое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь можно эту заготовку доработать до нужного вида.

---

Для удобства добавлю еще ряд дополнительных комментариев.

**Базовые типы свойств:**
Все пользовательские свойства имеют в основе какой-то базовый тип и отличаются, как правило, формой работы в админской части. К примеру, свойства дата имеет базовый тип Число. Вот список этих основных типов:

- Строка - S
- Число - N
- Список - L
- Файл - F
- Привязка к элементам - E
- Привязка к разделам - G

**Хранение данных в базе**

Значение каждого свойства может иметь две составляющие - это VALUE и DESCRIPTION

**Функция вывода в форме редактирования элемента**

В описанном примере это **GetPropertyFieldHtml** и у нее три аргумента:

- *$arProperty* - массив данных по этому типу свойств
- *$value* - значение хранимое в базе данных для конкретного элемента
  инфоблока
- *$strHTMLControlName* - массив с контрольными данными для формы на
  странице редактирования элемента инфоблока

---

Конкретно ваш случай с временем.

Тут два пути, зависит от деталей задачи.

1. Выводите свойство как строку с маской 00:00 (может с секундами
   00:00:00)
2. Выводите поле с календарем, как при вводе даты

В обоих случаях перед сохранением и выводом добавляете свои обработчики.
Пример функции выше с обработчиками будет такой:

```
    public function GetUserTypeDescription()
    {
        return array(
            "PROPERTY_TYPE"        => "S", #-----один из стандартных типов
            "USER_TYPE"            => "MYIDCODE", #-----идентификатор типа свойства
            "DESCRIPTION"          => "Название свойства",
            "GetPropertyFieldHtml" => array("CIBlockNewProperty", "GetPropertyFieldHtml"),
            "ConvertToDB" => array(__CLASS__, "ConvertToDB"), #-----функция конвертирования данных перед сохранением в базу данных
            "ConvertFromDB" => array(__CLASS__, "ConvertFromDB"), #-----функция конвертации после извлечения значения из базы данных и перед показом в форме редактирования элемента инфоблока
        );
    }
```

Как логично вытекает эти функции надо добавить в наш класс. Если брать пример с календарем, то можно так:

```
public static function ConvertToDB($arProperty, $arValue)
{
    if (strlen($arValue['VALUE'])) {
        $time = new \Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime($arValue['VALUE']);
        $arValue['VALUE'] = $time->getTimestamp();
    }
    return $arValue;
}

public static function ConvertFromDB($arProperty, $arValue)
{
    if ($arValue['VALUE'] && defined('ADMIN_SECTION') && ADMIN_SECTION===true) {//мы так же проверяем, чтобы форматировалось только в админке
        $time = Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime::createFromTimestamp($arValue['VALUE']);
        $arValue['VALUE'] = $time;
    }
    return $arValue;
}
```

И последнее, это вывод поля с календарем на странице редактирования. Берем стандартный Битриксовский:

```
public function GetPropertyHtml($arProperty, $value, $strHTMLControlName)
{
    $ret = '<div class="adm-input-wrap adm-input-wrap-calendar"><input class="adm-input adm-input-calendar" type="text" name="'.$strHTMLControlName["VALUE"].'" size="23" value="'.$value['VALUE'].'">';
    $ret .= '<span class="adm-calendar-icon" title="Нажмите для выбора даты" onclick="BX.calendar({node:this, field:\''.$strHTMLControlName["VALUE"].'\', form: \'\', bTime: true, bHideTime: false});"></span>';
    $ret .= '</div>';
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Пример все же существует](http://blog.d-it.ru/dev/lazy-programmer-and-the-variety-of-properties-of-an-infoblock-in-the-b/). По аналогии унаследуйтесь от свойства "Дата\Время" и создайте себе тип поля "Время" просто отрезав нужную часть или используя что-то свое.

UPD1: Подробный [пример](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/107201/blog/6730/) про добавление кастомного свойства.
Спасибо @ka3a.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/77460)

Comment: @Denis: Это нормальный ответ. Ссылка лишь дополняет ответ - "унаследуйтесь от свойства "Дата\Время" и создайте себе тип поля "Время" просто отрезав нужную часть или используя что-то свое."

Comment: Дополню ответ [ссылкой.](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/107201/blog/6730/)
Тут наглядный пример, как создавать полностью свой тип свойства ИБ.